# XE8 & iOS 9.1: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

Delphi XE8 (on Windows 7 Professional) is getting this error when compiling for iOS 9.1 (Mac Mini on Yosemite, iPhone 5s on current iOS 9.1):

```
 [DCC Error] E2597 ld: file not found: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
```

All help appreciated.

[image: SDK Setup]

[image: Actual Error]

Comment: Did you add it to the SDK manager?

Comment: The CoreText file is in the SDK list. I didn't need to add it. Looking on the Mac, I see the CoreText is there (via a soft link).